# Does to use multiple view resolvers in order to decouple different kind of views make sense?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm considering usage of multiple view resolvers for different purpose. For instance, one view resolver will be applied on security web-pages (`403`, `500`, etc) and another will be resolve the rest of the pages. Does this decoupling make a sense? So, actual cofiguration is:

```xml
<bean id="securityViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/security/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I would say no, not to mention that this wouldn't even work as you cannot have multiple `UrlBasedViewResolver` instances. They always return a `View` regardless of the fact if it actually exists or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, you're right. I tried it just now and it didn't work. It seemed like the only resolver with the highest order was applied. It still didn't work when I replaced one of the `UrlBasedViewResolver` with `InternalResourceViewResolver`. How can I ever apply multiple resolvers? I mean, if the first resolver couldn't resolve a view, the second resolver try an so on...

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the class hierarchies as `InternalResourceViewResolver` is a `UrlBasedViewResolver`. Don't use `UrlBasedViewResolver` or better don't use JSP but use something like Thymeleaf for your templates.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did, but it doesn't give any answer. Is there a simple way to configure multiple view resolvers in order to resolve views from different directories?

Comment: As I stated don't use `UrlBasedViewResolver`s... Or create your own implementation which checks for the availability of the JSP.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok, I got that. But why could the `UrlBasedViewResolver` be only once created? Is it defined by the documentation? In the javadoc I could find only that UrlBasedViewResolver will check whether the specified resource actually exists.

Comment: An instance of a UrlBasedViewResolver must always be the last in line because to put it simply it gives no chance for any other view resolver to try if it fails. So there is no point having two UrlBasedViewResolvers

Comment: The `UrlBasedViewResolver`, although I suggest using the `InternalResourceViewResolver` because that detects which actual view class to use (it is a convenience subclass). The `UrlBasedViewResolver` simple construct a URL and forward (or redirects) to that URL. It doesn't check its existence. The checking is delegated to the [`checkResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractUrlBasedView.html#checkResource-java.util.Locale-) method of the `View`. For the `InternalResourceView` and `JstlView` this always is `true`